# move markers on google map smoothly from 1 place to another

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I have used this part in my code below is just a piece of it

The flow is-0-->

1) there is 1 marker in  (that.markerClusterer.markers_)   the first marker enters the loop gets the Current & the Changed Postion & goes in to Transition function & sets the Position this goes Good

2) But the Issue is when I Push 2 markers in (that.markerClusterer.markers_) the marker takes 1 step less i.e. the value of g is effected  Dont know why but according to me addition of 1 marker should not  impact it

I have tried a lot but couldn't find any solution.

```
function markClusterToShowById(id, position, text) {
    for (markers = that.markerClusterer.markers_, i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

    var marker = markers[i];
    if (marker.id2 == id2) {

        var currentPosition_lat = marker.getPosition().lat(),
        currentPosition_long = marker.getPosition().lng()
        new_lat = position.lat(),
        new_long = position.lng();
        var new_loc = [new_lat, new_long];
        var prev_loc = [currentPosition_lat, currentPosition_long];

       transition(new_loc, prev_loc, marker );

            break
    }
    }
    return result
}



function transition(new_loc, prev_loc, marker){
    g = 1;
    deltaLat = (new_loc[0] - prev_loc[0])/4;
    deltaLng = (new_loc[1] - prev_loc[1])/4;

    moveMarker(prev_loc, deltaLat, deltaLng, marker);
}

function moveMarker(prev_loc, deltaLat, deltaLng, marker){
    prev_loc[0] += deltaLat;
    prev_loc[1] += deltaLng;
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(prev_loc[0], prev_loc[1]);
    marker.setPosition(latlng);

    if(g!=4){
    g++;
    setTimeout(function() {
    moveMarker(prev_loc, deltaLat, deltaLng, marker);
    }, 10)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following the implementation Google for Marker Clustering.

Code:

```
<div id="map-container"><div id="map"></div></div>
<script src="markerclusterer.js"></script>
<script>
function initialize() {
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5074, 0.1278);

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
zoom: 3,
center: center,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var markers = [];
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5074, 0.1278)
});
markers.push(marker);

var options = {
imagePath: 'images/m'
};

var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, options);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

If you will check the Marker Clusterer Sample link, you'll see a smooth transition of marker grouping and ungrouping.

Hope this helps

## References:

[MarkerClusterer for Google Maps v3](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/docs/reference.html)

[Marker Clusterer – A Google Maps JavaScript API utility library](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer)

[Marker Clusterer Sample](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/examples/simple_example.html)